# Javascript How to extract Date and put in calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

I create a calendar like:

```
for( var i=1; i <=12; i++){
    $("#kalbody").append('<div id="kalenderLine' + i + '" class="kalenderLine"></div>');
    $("#kalenderLine"+i).append('<div id="month'+i+'" class="monthName">'+getMonthname(i)+'</div>');

    //tage für monate erstellen
    for( var mi=1; mi <=getDays(i,Year); mi++){             
        //wochenenden
        aktForDate = Year+"-"+i+"-"+mi;
        var nowM = new Date(aktForDate);
        var dayM = nowM.getDayName();

        if(dayM == "Sa" || dayM == "So"){
            wE=" weekend"
        }
        else{
            wE="";  
        }
        //wE="";
        $("#kalenderLine"+i).append('<div id="'+mi+'-'+i+'-'+Year+'" class="dayCell'+wE+'"> <span class="dayCellNr">'+mi+'</span> </div>');
    }
}
```

I want to create Holidays like:

> From         To
>   10.01.2017-11.02.2017

What I have to do for this? Any idea to solve this?

Comment: I d suggest you to use a library like momentjs for that:  https://momentjs.com/ . It looks to me that you'll spend time reinventing the wheel otherwise.